# Obtaining LNK2005 error with DLL Exported vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, vector

I have a DLL where I define a vector of objects. I have exported the vector. When I try to use it in my client I am getting LNK2005 errors.

A.lib(A.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: struct MyNamespace::MyStruct1 & __thiscall MyNamespace::MyStruct1::operator=(struct MyNamespace::MyStruct1 const &)" (??4MyStruct1@MyNameSpace@@QAEAAU01@ABU01@@Z) already defined
in B.obj

My Struct does not override the operator=, and I have used guards in my header files to ensure that they are imported only once. I am using VS2005

Comment: `I have a DLL where I define a vector of objects. I have exported the vector.`  You don't say what in that error message refers to this vector of objects.  We don't even know if that error has anything to do with the vector.  Please clarify what the vector is objects is called, and what MyStruct is.

Comment: MyStruct1 is the objects that are in the vector. The client uses the vector only and so I thought it must be a issue with the vector.

Comment: Make sure `MyStruct1` definition has `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the DLL, and `__declspec(dllimport)` when building the client. This is usually done by defining a macro that expands to one or the other.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Exactly the problem,Thanks that fixed it.